# VB connect to COM object

Tags: vb.net, com

Either I don't understand COM objects, either it's all that confusing.
I frequently 'create' , 'dispatch' COM objects - either in Python, either in VB ( `Obj = win32com.client.Dispatch('Visum.Visum')` or `Obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` respectively).
That's easy, obvious and everything's fine.
But how can I:
a) connect to COM object which is already running
b) get list of running processes which are COM objects

- in VB what is the reference, and additional info on: `CreateObject` command. In Python it's part of well defined, comprehensive library of `win32com` whereas in VB it's just single method without reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9k08y5(v=vs.80).aspx

Highly confusing (COM object,server? connection, dispatching, registering??)

Thanks for claryfying
Rafal
i2

Comment: a) Use the GetObject() function. b) makes no sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest reading a good introduction to COM. Personally, i think that 'Essential COM' by Don Box is the best book about COM. Spending a few hours with it will save you many hours later.

That being said, let's move to your questions.

a) In order to retrieve an existing COM object from VB, you need to call [`GetObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9waz863%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function. This will only work for COM objects which are registered with [Running Object Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Excel does this, so there shouldn't be any problems with that.

b) as Hans Passant correctly noted, this question doesn't make sense. Processes and COM objects are completely unrelated things, except for the fact that processes host the COM objects. It is similar to asking 'which processes are instances of class X'. However, a process can host a COM object (or many of them). These object can be alive only temporarily, so what would you expect there? Besides, many COM classes are implemented within dlls, but created instances obviously are hosted within a process - so what would you expect there?

Answer (score 0):

COM technology is something I didn't not use for a while, so sorry if some info might be wrong (anyway, I've got my book "Inside COM+ base services" with me!)

Briefly speaking, let's give a simplified definition of a COM object: it nothing else than a standard DLL with classes exposing a standard interface IUnkown with the following methods:

- AddRef: to register a client consuming the COM object
- Release: to unregister a client (usually unused objects stop running, but other might remain resident)
- QueryInterface: to get the address of a function

QueryInterface is used to dynamically retrieve the address of a function (late-binding) which is powerful (you don't have to know the DLL at compile time) but time consuming. On the other hand, you can directly reference the addresses of the functions at compile-time because those DLL are registered in the system (all the informations are stored in the registry)

Creating a new object or getting the address of a running object is done through RPC (remote procedure call) which will load and/or play the role of a proxy

So to create a new instance of a COM object, you will call CreateObject (in VB) (Co)CreateInstance in VC++ (or even c#?), while to get an executing instance, you might want to call GetObject().

Getting the list of COM objects is not that easy (I guess not possible at all) because, as told earlier, a COM object is nothing else but a DLL: this means that the library will mainly load in the address space of each process which access is private. Even for out-process COM objects (opposite to in-process) which are object shared between many processes (i.e.: Excel is an out-of-process COM object: you don't load the DLL in your application's address space), they are loaded by a host (rpc.exe or a proprietary host)

Hope this helps
Serge