# Write into excel that is already open with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a Windows forms application that has two TextBoxes and a button.
I would like to be able to write to an Excel spreadsheet automatically but also manually (not through the program, and while it is running). All of that is working. The problem I have is when I am opening the form and the spreadsheet is already open, it creates a readonly copy and saves it in default location for Excel (It sometimes crahes when trying to save changes too). The problem is the `App.Workbooks.Open` line of code. Is there an alternative to `Open` if the spreadsheet is already open?
Can you write into an Excel by just "referring" to it and not opening the document again?
Here is my code:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Dim App As New Excel.Application
Dim Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim Workbook As Excel.Workbook

Public Function LookForSpace()
    Dim IsBlank As Boolean
    Dim Counter As Integer
    IsBlank = False
    Counter = 1
    While IsBlank = False
        Workbook.Save()
        If CStr(Worksheet.Cells(Counter, 1).Value) = "" And CStr(Worksheet.Cells(Counter, 2).Value) = "" Then
            IsBlank = True
        Else
            Counter = Counter + 1
        End If
    End While
    Return Counter
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Workbook = App.Workbooks.Open("Path\example.xlsx")
    Catch
        MsgBox("Dokument nicht gefunden")
        Me.Close()
    End Try
    Try
        Worksheet = Workbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
        App.Visible = True
    Catch
        MsgBox("Tabelle nicht gefunden!")
        Me.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim YIndex As Integer
    YIndex = LookForSpace()
    Worksheet.Cells(YIndex, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
    Worksheet.Cells(YIndex, 2).Value = TextBox2.Text
    Workbook.Save()
End Sub
```

The LookForSpace function just checks for a new Line to write in.

Please tell me if something is not clear because I am not a native english speaker.

Any help would be appreciated as I have been strugling with this for a week!

Comment: *The problem is the `App.Workbooks.Open` line* - no, the problem is the `As New Excel.Application` line. If you want to connect to an existing Excel process, [do so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13817607/11683).

Comment: @GSerg Thank you very very much!